# JS On form event (submit failed) get the JSON responce error code

Tags: javascript, json

After you summit the form and get  submit failed response I'm trying to get form the JSON response the error code.

This is what is generated after you submit the form.

```
submitFail {"message":"Request failed ","status":400,"response":{"message":"failed","errorCode":2}}
```

My code

```
.on('submitFail', e => {
    console.log('submitFail', e.detail.message);
})
```

the `e.detail.message` gives me the

```
submitFail {"message":"Request failed ","status":400,"response":{"message":"failed","errorCode":2}}
```

I want to get the errorCode and his value. In this case 2.

Comment: What's `e` in the event handler?

Comment: hi @DaveNewton Yes.

Comment: "Yes" is not a valid answer to that question.